# How to write to multiple trace sources

Tags: c#, trace

How do you write to multiple trace sources other than:

```
tss.ForEach(x => x.WriteLine());
```

(assuming a `ForEach` extension method)

i.e. is there a way of composing traces? or should I just write a helper method/use foreach?

Comment: In what part of your code are you doing this? In normal code, you shouldn't have to access the sources at all. `Trace.WriteLine` should write to all of the configured sources.

Comment: Is this Systems.Diagnostic trace? If so, like Jim says, this is done by registering more listeners to the Trace or TraceSource and each write is broadcast to all.